# MongoDB and Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: mongodb, entity-framework-core, nosql

So, I've read repeatedly that EF Core will support NoSQL databases but I can't seem to find any "official" NoSQL database providers, or even a NoSQL framework in the source code. (By "find" I mean search for "nosql".)

I've had a quick look at [ADO.NET](https://www.cdata.com/ado/) (paid) and [crhairr/EntityFrameworkCore.MongoDb](https://github.com/crhairr/EntityFrameworkCore.MongoDb) but they are both third-party. MongoDB (the specific database I was looking into) has their own .NET driver but it doesn't seem to integrate EF Core.

Anyway, what I really want to know is:

1. Does/will EF Core support NoSQL databases? What does "support" entail?
2. Does/will the MongoDB .NET driver support EF Core?

The results of my research so far seem to indicate that I'm misunderstanding something and it would be great if anyone could point it out.

Comment: The team has commited to a CosmosDB provider: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/wiki/roadmap

Comment: There really is not such thing as "NoSQL" in the same sense as "SQL" Databases. Unlike RDBMS that support SQL ( or more to the point ANSI-SQL), all "NoSQL" offerings are completely different; Different syntax, different storage, different intended usage purposes. If you want to ask a question of a specific technology, then that's what you ask. But casting a broad net is way too broad since none of the different solutions really share anything in common.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoSQL with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570098/nosql-with-entity-framework-core)

Comment: https://github.com/crhairr/EntityFrameworkCore.MongoDb

Answer (score 6):

Currently, the 2.1 EF Core roadmap doesn't show any new providers for NoSQL DBs.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/roadmap)

Yet, they are now focused for Azure Cosmos, which is a cloud DB service. In Cosmos, you can use MongoDB API. More info about the progress (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8443) and Cosmos & MongoDB(
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-dotnet)

For non third party MongoDB provider, it will take some time. You must understand, that .NET Core is a huge change from .NET Framework, because it now embodies the open source culture. Many libraries and tools are available and will be available without "Made by Microsoft" stamp. It's up for the community to create libraries and tools for .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has now released an officially supported EF Core provider (currently in preview).

Github repo: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-efcore-provider

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.EntityFrameworkCore

Issue/bug tracker:
https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/EF/issues/EF-63